# simple event c#

Tags: c#, events, exception

I have two classes, and i have to make an event to communicate between these classes.

```
Class a
{
    public delegate void delegat(int a);
    public event delegat exit;
    ...
    private void a_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
         // My event named exit should run here, but I get exception!
        exit(100);
    }
}

Class b
{
    a instance=new a();
    a.exit+=new a.delegat(my_fun);
    ...
    private void my_fun(int x)
    {
        if(x==100)
        do_smth;
        ...
    }
}
```

But the thing is that i get exception: "object reference not set to an instance of an object".
I can't understand what Am I doing wrong? Where should I make a new instance of this? 
Thanks for help!

Comment: How do you run this code? Do you create an instance of b? Are you sure the exception comes from the same instance of a as the one you have in b?

Comment: Your biggest problem is that you're calling non-static methods on the class. You make an instance of a, called "instance", but then never use it, as you're calling everything directly on a. Call them on "instance" instead, and see what happens.

Comment: instance of 'a' class is made when I push some button on 'b' form. Then 'a' class form is shown by a.ShowDialog() function and I do some things on 'a' form. As You can see my event should fire when other event fires(formClosed event on 'a' form). Maybe is something wrong with that?

Comment: And yes, i'm sure that exception comes from these part: `private void a_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
     exit(100);//here should run my event named exit but i get exception!
     }`

Comment: Hoeloe - i found these mistake:
I should write smth like that:
    `instance.exit+=new a.delegat(my_fun);`

instead of

    `a.exit+=new a.delegat(my_fun);`

But it still throws an exception.

Comment: @PawełAdamczyk see my detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign the `exit` event on the *class* itself and not the *instance* e.g.

```
a.exit += ...
```

Should be:

```
instance.exit += ...
```

You also aren't checking whether your `exit` event has been assigned before attempting to fire it. There are other issues which you haven't taken into consideration like race conditions.

Here is a general example of a relatively safe way of handling events e.g.

```
public class A
{
    public delegate void ExitHandler(object sender, int a);
    public event ExitHandler Exit;
    ...
    private void a_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnExit(100);
    }

    protected virtual void OnExit(int a)
    {
        // take a reference to the event (incase it changes)
        var handler = Exit;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, a);
        }
    }

}

public class B
{
    private A _a;

    public B()
    {
        _a = new A();
        _a.Exit += (sender, value) => my_fun(value);
    }

    private void my_fun(int x)
    {
        if(x==100)
            do_smth;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but I would also recommend using the conventions for event arguments (object that inherits from `EventArgs`)

Comment: @ken2k that's probably more of a preference, I prefer `EventArgs` over delegates myself. However, there is no issue using delegates.

Comment: best practice also having `protected` method for raising event

Comment: [Here's the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833085(v=vs.95).aspx) for event/delegates conventions. Another important thing is the `object sender` first parameter for event handlers.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky That's subjective. If you don't intend on deriving from the class then there is no reason to make it protected.

Comment: If class is not `sealed` then somebody else can inherit from your class :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Yes, however, there is no mention of the class being exposed as a base class or even any talk of it being inherited. I usually develop in a "implement what I need" sort of way rather than "implement what I *may* need" - However, for reference I have updated the signature as either way it doesn't affect what the OP is trying to do :) I also updated the delegate to pass the sender (good point @ken2k)

Answer (score 0):

Verify if there is any subscriber exist to your event before raising it:

```
if (exit != null)
    exit(100);
```

Another option - subscribing dummy event handler when you are defining event in class A:

```
public event delegat exit = (_) => { };
```

Also use PascalCase naming for types, events and methods. And there is predefined delegate in .NET which receives one argument and returns void: `Action<T>`

Answer (score 0):

I would change "class a" code for calling the event to as follows:

```
Class a
{
  public delegate void delegat(int a);
  public event delegat exit;
  ...
  private void a_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
     if (this.exit != null)  // just in case a_FormClosed fires before assigning the event
         exit(100);//here should run my event named exit but i get exception!
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
namespace foo
    {
    public delegate void delegat(int a);
    Class a
    {
      public event delegat exit;
      private void a_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
if(exit != null)
{
         exit(100);//here should run my event named exit but i get exception!
    }
         }
     }
    }

     Class b
     {
      a instance=new a();
      instance.exit+=new delegat(my_fun);
      ...
      priavte void my_fun(int x)
      {
       if(x==100)
        do_smth;
       ...
       }
     }
```